# How do I print the first few lines of a makefile (-Wall -g flags)?

Tags: linux, makefile

How do I get the first *n* lines of the output of a makefile (specifically, my complier is g++). Either a script in linux or in the makefile would work (if you could provide both, that'll be even better).

I have tried

> make | head -n 5

but it's not working.

Currently, the process I go through is tedious; I'm piping the output to a text file before using head on it (then having to delete the file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the messages from the compiler appear on standard error rather than standard output, you need to redirect both:

```
make 2>&1 | head -n 20
```

(I think 5 lines will be too small to be useful.)

Comment: Doesn't that risk the make being killed by a SIGPIPE if there's a lot of output?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't seem to be a problem for the OP.  If it is, then I'd probably replace `head -n 20` with `sed -n 1,20p` then all the input will be read but only the first 20 lines will be printed (so no SIGPIPE issue).

Comment: Oh, thank you. I completely forgot that the messages are being displayed on standard error!

Comment: I'm getting an Ambigious output redirection error in terminal from the "make 2>&1 | head -n 20" command

Comment: Which shell are you using?  A C shell derivative?  You shouldn't get that from `bash` or `ksh`.  (Checked: `tcsh` gives that error.  Well, assuming that 'change to a real shell; leave sea shells on the sea shore' isn't acceptable advice, then you need `make |& head -n 20`, I believe — but you can check the manual as well as I can.)

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I'm not able to change my tcsh shell but the last command works great!